# Java NoClassDefFoundError with inherited class

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I've recently started learning Java however I'm having a few problems related to the `NoClassDefFoundError`. I've tried to research solutions from this site and elsewhere but still haven't been able to solve them. I run my programs from the Windows 7 Command Prompt with the CLASSPATH environment variable set instead of defining it for each program run. It's set to `C:`. To troubleshoot, I created a test package with a simplified directory structure.

In `C:\test`, I have `Shape.java` and `Circle.java`. `Shape.java` looks like this:

```
package test;

class Shape {
    void draw() { System.out.println("Drawing a new shape"); }
}
```

and `Circle.java` looks like this:

```
package test;

public class Circle extends Shape {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circle round = new Circle();
        round.draw();
    }
}
```

If I compile both `Shape.java` and `Circle.java` from `C:\` in the command prompt with operations like

```
C:\>javac test\Shape.java 
C:\>javac test\Circle.java
```

and the run the compiled `Circle.class` file like

```
C:\java test\Circle
```

I get the output I expect:

```
Drawing a new shape
```

However, if I compile the `Shape.java` and `Circle.java` from inside the `C:\test` like

```
C:\test>javac Shape.java 
C:\test>javac Circle.java
```

and then try to run `Circle.class` from anywhere like

```
C:\test>java Circle
```

or like this

```
C:\> java test\Circle
```

I get the following error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Circle (wrong name: t
est/Circle)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Could someone explain why it is that the JAVA files compile from within the `C:\test` folder but the compiled Circle file produces that error? Is there something wrong with my CLASSPATH? Thanks for reading and for your hopefully forthcoming solutions!

EDIT: I've done a bit more testing and it turns out that if I compile the `Shape.java` and `Circle.java` files from the `C:\test` directory but run it from the `C:\` directory, it works. Does this change anything?

EDIT 2: After more testing, it turns out that I can in fact compile and run the Shape.java and Circle.java files from within the C:\test directory as long as I use the command java test.Circle. I misunderstood the way in which the JVM looks for classes.  I understand now that it uses the same method as the compiler when it analyses package import statements.

Comment: Use eclipse workbench.

Comment: Use `java test.Circle`

Comment: You should seriously use an IDE like Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be anywhere on the system, as long as you have a classpath bounded in .

Only then would the java VM be able to scan the classpath, and locate the class `test.Circle` in the package `test`.

So, the correct execution is `java test.Circle` (always), and the classpath needs to point to something which would have `\test\Circle.class` available. Check that the `Circle.class` is where you expect it.

Comment: +1 - Just to be really sure (basically you correctly described it): the classpath needs to point to the directory which itself contains the `test` directory (= package) - e.g. if the class `test.Circle` is located at `c:\bin\test\Circle.class`, then classpath needs to point to `c:\bin`

Comment: Thanks a lot for such quick replies! My Shape.class and Circle.class files are both created in the C:\test directory. What do you mean by the classpath being bounded in? Should the directory from which I compile and run the Circle.class file make any difference if my classpath is set to C:\ which has the test\Circle.class available?

Comment: I meant to bind it c-kolon-backslash, but I think the editor kind of omitted my keystrokes :) Anyway, as Andreas clarifies, the classpath is a collection of roots of the search tree. It doesn't matter if it inside a directory, in a zip file (or jar file) or even from a network url. The is the 'magic' of the classloader

Comment: But then shouldn't the JVM start at the classpath when searching for classes regardless of where I run the files from?

Comment: Yes, but I believe you specified java Circle, which is not correct. You have to use the fully qualified name of the class which is 'test.Circle'.... Should you be in c:\test, you would probably write java -cp .. test.Circle

Comment: Ahh, so the main thing is to give the fully qualified name of the class, which is test.Circle since it exists within a package I've specified. If the CLASSPATH environmental variable is already set to C:\, why do have to specify it again with the -cp option? Why would the directory from which I run the file change the CLASSPATH?

Comment: Just done some more testing and I think you were completely right. I don't necessarily need to use the -cp option. Even if my CLASSPATH is still set to C:\, I can run the Circle.class file from within the C:\test directory as long as I use the command java test.Circle. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your classpath represents where you have stored your classes. As your have set your classpath as `c:\`. So when you launch jvm using `java` command then, it will load the needed classes form `c:\`. Your code is working when you compile and run the program from `C:` because the classes will be compiled and will be present in `C:` in that case, so no problem. But when you compile your classes from `c:\test`, your .class files will be present in c:\test but your classpath will load classes only form `c:\` and NOT `c:\test`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Does that mean that as a general rule, I should only compile and run my programs from the classpath directory?

Comment: You need to put the compiled classes with proper package strucutre in the classpath. Or you can always add the current directory to the classpath if you want. Once you have your classes in the classpath then you can run it from anywhere.

Comment: But the Shape.class and Circle.class files were being generated in the C:\test directory. Is this not proper package structure?

Answer (score 0):

to compile, use

```
javac -d . Shape.java
javac -d . Circle.java
```

To run

```
java test.Circle
```

`-d` is for choosing the destination directory
`.` means the current directory
So in your current Directry `C:\test\` , when you compile the java file, a new directory named `test`(package name) will be created and class files will be inside it.
ie.
`C:\test\test\Shape.java` and `C:\test\test\Circle.java`

Comment: It worked! Can you explain why the compiler doesn't automatically create the directory C:\test\test when I compile the Shape.java and Circle.java files from within the C:\test directory?

Comment: @user2582713 If it worked, You can accept the answer by clicking the tick mark on left side to my answer. The answer to your comment, It is obvious that we expect the class file to be generated in current directory but I cant give you the exact explaination. You can ask it as a new question if you want.

Comment: -d . is the default. The real point is to compile from the head of the package structure, not the directory where the source files are.

Comment: @EJP That's the impression I'm getting. Do you know why that's the case?

Comment: @EJP if -d . is by default, then why package directory is not created by default inside current directory but is only created when -d . is given.